# SQL Efficiency: WHERE IN Subquery vs. JOIN then GROUP

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

As an example, I want to get the list of all items with certain tags applied to them.  I could do either of the following:

```
SELECT Item.ID, Item.Name
FROM Item
WHERE Item.ID IN (
    SELECT ItemTag.ItemID
    FROM ItemTag
    WHERE ItemTag.TagID = 57 OR ItemTag.TagID = 55)
```

Or

```
SELECT Item.ID, Item.Name
FROM Item
LEFT JOIN ItemTag ON ItemTag.ItemID = Item.ID
WHERE ItemTag.TagID = 57 OR ItemTag.TagID = 55
GROUP BY Item.ID, Item.Name
```

Or something entirely different.

In general (assuming there is a general rule), what's a more efficient approach?

Comment: @Larsenal: you can replace a `LEFT JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN` in your second query, the results will be the same. A `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL`s for the rows in `ItemTag` that do not have a corresponding `Item.ID`, and your `WHERE` condition will filter them out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT Item.ID, Item.Name
> FROM Item
> WHERE Item.ID IN (
>     SELECT ItemTag.ItemID
>     FROM ItemTag
>     WHERE ItemTag.TagID = 57 OR ItemTag.TagID = 55)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> SELECT Item.ID, Item.Name
> FROM Item
> LEFT JOIN ItemTag ON ItemTag.ItemID = Item.ID
> WHERE ItemTag.TagID = 57 OR ItemTag.TagID = 55
> GROUP BY Item.ID
> ```

Your second query won't compile, since it references `Item.Name` without either grouping or aggregating on it.

If we remove `GROUP BY` from the query:

```
SELECT  Item.ID, Item.Name
FROM    Item
JOIN    ItemTag
ON      ItemTag.ItemID = Item.ID
WHERE   ItemTag.TagID = 57 OR ItemTag.TagID = 55
```

these are still different queries, unless `ItemTag.ItemId` is a `UNIQUE` key and marked as such.

`SQL Server` is able to detect an `IN` condition on a `UNIQUE` column, and will just transform the `IN` condition into a `JOIN`.

If `ItemTag.ItemID` is not `UNIQUE`, the first query will use a kind of a `SEMI JOIN` algorithm, which are quite efficient in `SQL Server`.

You can trasform the second query into a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  Item.ID, Item.Name
FROM    Item
JOIN    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ItemID
        FROMT  ItemTag
        WHERE  ItemTag.TagID = 57 OR ItemTag.TagID = 55
        ) tags
ON      tags.ItemID = Item.ID
```

but this one is a trifle less efficient than `IN` or `EXISTS`.

See this article in my blog for a more detailed performance comparison:

- [**`IN` vs. `JOIN` vs. `EXISTS`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/)

Answer (score 4):

I think it would depend on how the optimizer handles them, it may even be the case that you end up with the same performance. Display execution plan is your friend here.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Item.ID, Item.Name
...
GROUP BY Item.ID
```

This is not valid T-SQL.  Item.Name must appear in the group by clause or within an aggregate function, such as SUM or MAX.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much impossible (unless you're one of those crazy guru DBAs) to tell what will be fast and what won't without looking at the execution plan and/or running some stress tests.

Comment: In fact, it's easy to say: the second one is way faster. It will just refuse to compile in a nanosecond or so.

Comment: @Quassnoi Wouldn't that make it slower? It takes an infinite amount of time to return the result...

Answer (score 0):

run this:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON
```

then run each version of the query

you can see if they return the same plan, and if not look at the TotalSubtreeCost on the first row of each and see how different they are.

Answer (score 0):

Performance always seems to get the vote, but you also hear "it is cheaper to buy hardware than programmers"

The second wins on performance.

Sometimes it is nice to look at SQL and know the purpose, but that's what comments are for. The first query is using the other table for a filter - pretty straight forward.

The second one would make more sense (from an understanding purpose and not performance)  using distinct instead of group by. I would expect some aggregates to be in the select, but there aren't any. Speed kills.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is more efficient in MySQL. MySQL will re-execute the query within the IN statement for every WHERE condition test.